# Complex Name validation with PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a project and a part of it requires to validate name fields.

Here is the logic:

> If any name value contains an 'i' after 'e' that is not after 'c',
>   then issue an error.

I know I should try to write something and then share it, but in this case I have no idea how its done. I know `preg_match()` can be a solution , but again I have no idea how its done.

I know I will get down vote due to not writing anything, but hopefully I get an answer.

Thanks Guys,

Comment: What you are looking for is regex. Try it and if could not get solution, then post whatever you tried here.

Comment: The English language contains [many exceptions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_not_following_the_I_before_E_except_after_C_rule) to this "rule" (as with any "rule" in this language).

Comment: Please deem your question resolved by awarding the green tick to the answer that most helped you / that you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use preg_match() as you say.

Here it is your pattern:
**[^c]ei** - for all strings, where there is NO **C** berfore **EI**

```
$badString = 'ceiling';
$goodString = 'vein';
$pattern = '/[^c]ei/';
preg_match($pattern,$badString); // 0
preg_match($pattern,$goodString); //1
```

If you want all strings that match with 'cei', you don't need regex.
You can use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
$goodString = 'ceiling';
$badString = 'vein';
stripos($badString, 'cei'); // -1
preg_match($goodString,'cei'); //1
```

**Important!** Please check manual for returning values of both functions.

Comment: I just check it. And it provide output that i wrote. Can you display, how you did it?

Comment: Based on your answer, 'vein' is the badstring, but 'ceiling' is goodstring because 'c' should be after 'ei' in order to validate. It helped me by the way thanks man

Comment: fixed it. I forgot about slashes

Comment: @ShahGhafoori can you provide samples of good and bad strings to clearify?

Comment: @Dmytrechko sorry my first comment was wrong, what I mean was that c should be BEFORE 'ei'.  
 'Ceilena' is a good string because it has 'EI' and there is a 'C' before 'EI' but  'VEIN' is bad one because it has EI but there is no C before that

Comment: ehmm, guy. Sou you just can use 'cei'??

Comment: if there is a name which has 'ei' somewhere in it, then it should have a c before it. I know its weird but the client is asking for it

Comment: Just provide different samples please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) (or `strpos()` if case sensitivity is required). To demonstrate:

```
$str1 = "weird";
$str2 = "ceiling";

checkCEI($str1); // Echoes "Error for weird"
checkCEI($str2); // output true, as it passes the test

function checkCEI($str) {
    if (stripos($str, "ei") !== false && stripos($str, "cei") === false) {
     return "Error for ".$str;
    }
    return true;
}
```